# Manipulating the first item in a list in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, automation, gspread

I am working on my first python project.

I am pulling user information from google sheets into a script with gspread.

From gspread I am pulling first name, last name, email, etc.

I need to manipulate these data points into a new datapoints: username

Username for John Smith would be jsmith (first initial last name)

gspread pulls the cells as a list, ie [John, Smith]

How would I go about creating the logic to pull the first letter from the first item in the list, then adding it to the second item in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script, the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Slicing an iterable datatype is done with square brackets. the first item of a list would be `mylist[0]`, and the first character of a string would be `mystr[0]`. If you have a list like: `mylist = ["john", "smith"]` creating jsmith would look like `mylist[0][0] + mylist[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
nameList = ["John", "Smith"]
# Grab the first letter of the first element in the list then combine it to the second element of the list
nameList[0][0] + nameList[1]
```

Output:

```
'JSmith'
```